# Apache Airflow dag schedules in midnight UTC

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I created Apache Airflow DAG with following default args. I want this DAG to run every day at 10PM UTC but it's always running at 12AM UTC and ignoring the date time I had set in start_date. Is this not the right way? Thanks.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': config.OWNER,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 10, 14, 22, 0, 0),
    'email': [config.ALERT_EMAIL],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'retries': 2,
}

# DAG
dag = DAG('Test',
          default_args=default_args,
          description='Initial setup',
          schedule_interval='@daily')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [cron format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) in your `schedule interval` argument like this:

```
# DAG
dag = DAG('Test',
          default_args=default_args,
          description='Initial setup',
          schedule_interval='0 22 * * *')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `schedule_interval` you have at least three options:

- datetime.timedelta
- dateutil.relativedelta
- cron style string

The `schedule_interval` defines how often that DAG runs. This timedelta object is added to your latest task instance’s execution_date to figure out the next schedule. And keep in mind that: `start_date` for the task, determines the execution_date for the first task instance.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is correct.

I have encountered an issue where, in Airflow 2.0, schedule_interval is ignored when put in the default_args.  When I removed it and put it in the DAG declaration, all worked. I could test this by looking at the DAG details in the UI.

Example:

```
default_args = {
  'owner': 'Hector Hoffman',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date':start_date,
  'schedule_interval': '0 5 * * *',
  'email': ['hector@email.com'],
  'email_on_failure': True,
  'email_on_retry': False,
  'retries': 0,
  'on_failure_callback': task_fail_slack_alert
}
```

Results in:
[image]

Whereas, when I put it in the DAG:

```
with models.DAG(
        "dealstampede_workflow",
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval='0 5 * * *'
) as dag:
```

Results in:

[image]

If anyone has any insight as to why the schedule_interval doesn't work in the default_args I'd appreciate feedback. Thanks.